# how to make Database option in j2me for S40 development?

Tags: database, netbeans, mobile, java-me, nokia-s40

I've been searching on how to make a database in J2ME for S40 development, but it seems that Derby is too complicated and RMS doesn't have the capabilities of adding other columns and rows...
I just want to know if there's anything like SQLite for S40 development.
Or if there's a tutorial on how to use the Database component in the Visual Midlet for S40 development. because I don't know how to use it, and I really need to make a database for my application.

btw, I can't get rid of the database and use file communication because it's slow and complicated as well.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is not supported on Series40. In fact, I am not aware of any SQL databases that is available for Series40. RMS is your best option at this time. I can recommend using an object persistence framework such as [Floggy](http://floggy.sourceforge.net/) for easier development with RMS.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite never support with Java ME.  Look at [List of database framework for Java ME development.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/230853/JME/Mobile/List-Database-ME) But I suggest don't use 3rd party database for S40. Because most of the s40 mobiles having small amount of heap memory (not more than 2 MB). So better way, Go with RMS.